# PHP: How to print sub values from multi-level array (Stripe object)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments

I get the below object which returns from retrieving a Stripe session ID (the object is called `$order`).

I am able to print values from the first object level using e.g. `print_r($order->id);`

How can I print values from the second level, such as amount or currency ?
I tried `print_r($order->display_items->amount);` and `print_r($order->display_items['amount']);`

**PHP:**

```
Stripe\Checkout\Session JSON: { 
    "id": "some_id", 
    "object": "checkout.session", 
    "billing_address_collection": null, 
    "cancel_url": "some_url", 
    "client_reference_id": null, 
    "customer": "some_id", 
    "customer_email": null, 
    "display_items": [{
        "amount": 2990, // this is what I need
        "currency": "eur", // this is what I need
        "custom": {
            "description": null, 
            "images": null, 
            "name": "some_product"
        },
        "quantity": 1, 
        "type": "custom"
    }], 
    "livemode": false, 
    "locale": "en", 
    "mode": "payment", 
    "payment_intent": "some_id", 
    "payment_method_types": [ "card" ], 
    "setup_intent": null, 
    "submit_type": null, 
    "subscription": null, 
    "success_url": "some_url"
}
```

**Update:** 
If I use `print_r($order->display_items);` I get the below. Could I assign this to an array and then print from there (if there is no other solution) ?

```
Array ( [0] => Stripe\StripeObject Object ( [amount] => 2990 [currency] => eur [custom] => Stripe\StripeObject Object ( [description] => [images] => [name] => some_product ) [quantity] => 1 [type] => custom ) )
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be missing something, but wouldn't [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) work here?

Comment: @mtr.web: Thank you. I don't need the whole object, only specific values from it. E.g. I want to use the amount for a field on that page. Can I achieve that with json_decode ?

Comment: Super inefficient, but `json_decode($yourStripeJsonVar)['display_items']['amount']` should work

Comment: @mtr.web: Thanks again. If this is not a good approach what would you suggest instead ? From the whole object I only need 4 or 5 values. Also, how do I print the amount with the above approach ? I tried print_r(json_decode($order)['display_items']['amount']);

Comment: @Jdub: Thank you. That does not work either. If I use $order->display_items I get  all the values there but I cannot select specific sub values from it.

Comment: @Jdub: No difference. What if I assign $order->display_items to an array. Could I print it that way ?

Comment: @Jdub: I updated my question to show how this looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r($obj->display_items[0]->amount);`

Just be sure your JSON is valid :) https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That is exactly what I needed and it works perfectly. Thank you so much !

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It helped me much.